# Debugging access report performance

Tags: sql, windows, ms-access

I've been given a access database which has a really long running report and tasked with finding out why / how to improve it.

pulling the SQL out I see the report is using stacked queries... Each query references another query, and then another, and then another. Until finally we get down to 3 or 4 low level queries that actually reach out to tables rather than other queries.

In researching good ways to debug access queries/performance I stumbled across several articles referencing the  showplan.out that can be output.  I'm only finding old tutorials and references that are no longer relevant or contain big disconnects in the process of setting this up because everything I've read and tried so far has failed.

Long story short, I figured out that most of the articles are referencing the JET engine which is used prior to 2007 and I needed to enable a different registry key.

I'm running Office 2013 and best I have found is I need to add the following registry entry.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engine\Debug]
"JETSHOWPLAN"="ON"
```

I have added this to my registry.  nothing beyond `\15.0\` existed prior to me adding this. I have restarted the access and my computer following this addition and i'm not seeing any output in my documents or the directory of the database i'm working on.  ( I also searched my computer for showplan.out just to e certain and found nothing )

can anyone offer any suggestions on what i'm missing here, or a better article on how to get  SQL performance/explanation information out of access?

This is 32 bit office 2013 running under 64 Bit Windows 7 Professional.

Thanks

//- Edit  ====================================================

For the next sole that runs into this problem.
running 32 Bit office 2013 under 64 Bit Windows you can simply drop the following into a .reg file and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Debug]
"JETSHOWPLAN"="ON"
```

restart Access and find showplan.out in "My Documents" as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ACE, and windows 7, then the key name is thus:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Debug
```

In the Debug folder, you thus create a NEW key called

```
JETSHOWPLAN
```

And inside of the above key place the string:

```
ON
```

However, if you using x64 bit version of windows (and 32 bit office 2010), then this is the key:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Debug
```

As noted, you then create a key inside of Debug called

```
 JETSHOWPLAN

 And the value is ON
```

When you run any query, then you find a document called SHOWPLAN.OUT in your “My Documents” folder.

Don’t forget to remove this, as the output file will grow fast, and you rather fast damage query performance.

Comment: completely missed the typo in the tutorial I ultimately pulled the Access Connectivity Engine reg key from...  I had 'Engine'  instead of 'Engines'. Thanks!